# Question about irrational numbers.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers

Consider some irrational number. For example we could take $\pi$. As we know $\pi = 3.1415...$. Now let's consider a sequence $[a]_{1}^{\infty}$. We build this sequence using this rule : $a_{i} = \beta_{j} \dots \beta_{k}$ , where $\beta_{j} \dots \beta_{k}$ is consecutive numbers in our irrational number and for $k = [1 \dots i-1]$ $a_{k}$ doesn't contain $\beta_{j} \dots \beta_{k}$.

For $\pi$ our sequence is : $a_{1} = 3$, $a_{2} = 1$, $a_{3} = 4$, $a_{4} = 15$ etc.

So my question is : does there some irrational number $\zeta$ , for which $[a(\zeta)]_{1}^{\infty} \ne \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Sure, any irrational whose expansion uses just two digits.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, there is some confusion about how exactly you construct the numbers $a_i$:

1. What is $j$ in the definition, and how is $k$ quantified? In saying $a_i=\beta_j\dots\beta_k$, you make it look like $k$ is a **fixed** number (dependent only on $i$), but then you say "for all $k=[1,\dots,i-1]$, which is very confusing.
2. What happens after all the digits appear? For example, what if the number you have is $0.123456789 + \frac{\pi}{10000000000}$? Then you have $a_1=1,\dots, a_9=9$, but what is $a_{10}$?

---

But, no matter that, two things are clear from your answer and they are enough to answer it:

1. You take an irrational number
2. You construct integers out of the decimal expansion of that number.

and the question is do you thus construct all integers.

The answer is no, and

$$0.101001000100001000001000000100000001\dots$$

shows why.

---

To see that the number I provided is irrational, you can prove that it cannot have repeating decimals, as it contains $n$ consequtive zeros for each $n\in\mathbb N$.

To see that the number cannot generate all integers, you can clearly see it cannot generate $2$ (or any other number with digits other than $1$ and $0$).

Comment: You might want to link to an explanation of why we know it's irrational: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesConstant.html

Comment: @user275313 I don't think it's *that* hard to see it's irrational, since it clearly has no repeating decimals (it has sequences of zeros of length $n$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$)

Comment: Really? A downvote? Can the downvoter please explain what is so *bad* and **wrong** about this answer?

Comment: You're right. I looked too quickly and though it was Liouville's constant (which it isn't), which is famous for being the first proven transcendental number. Thought I'd throw in a link 'cause it's cool.

Comment: I did downvote your answer, and the reasons are that I don't think it is OK to answer a question which you are not sure to understand correctly, and (even considering this just a way of speaking) that I think the answer lack some explanation (or some link to it); it's not obvious to everyone here that the number $0.1010010001\cdots$ is irrational. I will be happy to change my downvote to a upvote if you address this concern(s).

Comment: @mathbeing Thanks for answering. Overall, I think your downvote is an over-reaction, as downvotes typically mean that you think the answer is *wrong* or *harmful*, however if you only think that the answer *could be improved*, it is more common to first mention this in comments. I did edit my answer now, however.

Comment: I am relatively new to this site and I was under the impression that downvoting was the way to denote any critic (so to speak). Even having this into account I used to leave a comment when downvoting (I just didn't in yours until I saw your comment because I would essentially have said the same that user275313's first comment). Sorry for the confussion, understood!! I will proceed having that in mind in the future. :) (+2) Great answer by the way! ;)